# Creating Multirow Undefined Control Sequence

Tags: latex

I'm creating table from https://www.tablesgenerator.com/# but getting error with multirow:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\@sharp ->\multirow {2}{*}{}  
l.70 \multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\multirow{2}{*}{}}
```

I've tried removing the square brackets but didn't work.

```
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\multirow{2}{*}{}} \\
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{}                  \\ \hline
            &             &             \\
            &             &             \\
            &             &             \\
            &             &            
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I have all the packages installed. what can be done to resolve this please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `\usepackage{multirow}` if you want to use `\multirow`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\multirow{2}{*}{}} \\
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{}                  \\ \hline
            &             &             \\
            &             &             \\
            &             &             \\
            &             &            
\end{tabular}
\end{table}



\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Even though I couldn't fix it I found out that this is a problem occurs because of Texworks. package seems installed but not working.